# Software for SSL certificates management

Tags: linux, security

For my company I have to find a way to simplify the SSL certificates management.

Right now we have an excel file with all SSL certificates and their attributes. I would like to improve the process with an (web)application that:

- allow to visualize all certificates contained in a knowledge base
- allow to easily add a certificate in the knowledge base
- alert by email when a certificate is about to expire

Do you know if there is a software (on Linux) already exists or if I have to code mine ?

Answer (score 1):

Few weeks ago I got recommendation from networking expert for [XCA](http://xca.hohnstaedt.de/). It is hosted at http://xca.sourceforge.net/.

Supported Operating systems are:

- Linux
- Windows
- MAC OSX
- other Unix variants

I'm not sure if it can fulfill your alerts requirement. Maybe you or someone around can add support for this. Still better than having to code the whole app.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I finally coded the whole app in few days with python, django and bootstrap :)