# Certificate Manager Recomendations

Tags: ssl

I'm looking for recommendations for a (preferably free or open source!) platform for managing SSL certificates.

We currently have a number of certificates, issues from our own internal Microsoft CA, as well as purchase from external CA's that we need to keep a track of the expiry information on. Which we currently do in Outlook Calendars, but I can't help feel there has to be a better way.

I swear I found a project somewhere before (done by Microsoft?) , but my Google-fu is now failing, and I just can't find it :(

I've seen this one, [Software for SSL certificates management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2724/software-for-ssl-certificates-management), from many years ago ...